# Minimization problem with parameter

Tags: optimization

$a>0,\; b>0,\; S=$parameter $>0$.
$$a+b+\dfrac{S-2}{2(a+b)} \longrightarrow min$$
With condition that
$a\cdot b =1$

Using inequality of arithmetic and geometric means we get:

$$a+b+\dfrac{S-2}{2(a+b)} \geq 2+ \dfrac{S-2}{2(a+b)}$$
With equality when $a=b$. This is true, but the answer to this problem is that if  $S\leq 10$ this will indeed be the answer, but if $S>10$, $a=b$ no longer gives the best result.

I am mainly interested in relatively "simple" and short solutions and methods of this problem.

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange's approach to get a general solution yet?

Comment: I suggest you replace "b" by "1/a" (this is your condition). Then you have a function of "a" and "S". Compute its derivative and set it equal to zero. This will give you a relation between "a" and "S". You will proably find radicals of quadratics in "S".Does this help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $S\ge 10$, you can use AM-GM like this:
$$(a+b)+\dfrac{S-2}{2(a+b)} \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{S-2}{2}}$$
with equality iff $2(a+b)^2=S-2$. From this and $ab = 1$, you can solve for $a, b$.

Comment: Perfect! But I have a philosophical question: ok, this is the answer... but is this a solution? Well, look..there already was an inequality that was true for all $S>0$ and now there is a better inequality for $S\geq10$, do we know there isn't even better one for some $S$?

Comment: The key here is that it cannot be better, because we have found a minimum independent of $(a, b)$, which is in fact achieved for some value of $(a, b)$.